# pyaudioで録音すると音割れする

Tags: python, audio

pyaudioを使ったプログラムで録音すると
なぜか音割れが発生します　
ほかの録音アプリ等ではそのようなことは起きていませんので（標準で入っていたボイスレコーダー等）

このコードが原因かと疑っています
初心者なのでなぜこのようなことが起きるのかまったくわかりません
わかる人教えてください

```
import pyaudio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
import wave 
import numpy as np
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
"""
def audiostop(audio, stream,CHUNK,FORMAT,CHANNELS,RATE,RECORD_SECONDS):
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    audio.terminate()
def audio_save(audio,stream,CHUNK,FORMAT,CHANNELS,RATE,RECORD_SECONDS):
    wf = wave.open("rokuon5.wav", 'wb')
    wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
    wf.setsampwidth(audio.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
    wf.setframerate(RATE)
    wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
    wf.close()




def     read_plot_data(stream,frames,CHUNK,FORMAT,CHANNELS,RATE,RECORD_SECONDS):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)

audiodata = np.frombuffer(data, dtype='int16')#numpyへ変換
print(type(audiodata))
#plot.plot(audiodata)
#plot.draw()
#plot.pause(0.001)
#plot.cla()
```

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16 # int16型
CHANNELS = 1             # ステレオ
RATE = 44100             # 441.kHz
RECORD_SECONDS = 3

if **name** == '**main**':
audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = audio.open( format = FORMAT,
#record_time=10,
rate = RATE,
channels = CHANNELS,
input_device_index = 0,
input = True,
frames_per_buffer = CHUNK)
frames = []
for _ in range(int(RATE/CHUNK*RECORD_SECONDS)):
try:
read_plot_data(stream,frames,CHUNK,FORMAT,CHANNELS,RATE,RECORD_SECONDS)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
break

```
audiostop(audio,stream,CHUNK,FORMAT,CHANNELS,RATE,RECORD_SECONDS)
audio_save(audio,stream,CHUNK,FORMAT,CHANNELS,RATE,RECORD_SECONDS)
```

Comment: どうやってもコードをうまくのせれませんでした　すいません

Comment: コードを載せるには、
コードを貼り付け、前後を3つのバッククォート(\`)からなる行で囲むのが一番簡単です。
コード全体を4つのスペースで字下げしてもよいです。
参考: [コードと書式設定済みテキスト](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)。
なお、現在のコードには `main()` がありますが、`main` 関数の定義が見当たらない、`"""` が閉じられていないなど、奇妙な点がありますので、そもそもコードの貼り付けに失敗しているかも知れません。

Comment: 取り敢えずこんな風に公開されているサンプルコードを試して比較してみてはどうでしょう？ [PyAudio のサンプル](https://qiita.com/ekzemplaro/items/4dde6f6f02cca2adf2f5), [pyaudio - Playing and Recording Sound in Python](https://realpython.com/playing-and-recording-sound-python/#pyaudio_1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

解決しました　どうやら再生側の原因でした

別の方法で再生した場合きれいに取れてました